# One with the Shadows achievement - no Solitude quests?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I've done countless number of quests in 4 (riften, windhelm, whiterun, markath) of the cities and have done the special quests in 3 (windhelm, markath, whiterun) of them as well including the quest from Tonilia.

However, I have yet to receive a quest in Solitude and no matter how many times I drop and retake a different quest there are none in Solitude.
Has anyone experienced this problem?

Comment: I have played through the Thieve's Guild quest line 4 times (I like to have the skeleton key even if I'm not "playing a theif") and there always seems to be *one* city they give me less than the others; this most recent time I did 8 quest *each* in Whiterun and Solitude before my *first* Markath one. You just have to keep trying.

Answer (score 6):

Go to Vex and Delvin and pick up the radiant quests. If they're not the ones you want, just drop them immediately and pick up new ones.

Rinse and repeat until you get the quest(s) you want.

Vex and Delvin will talk smack, but there is no dis-benefit from dropping these quests. Or (if you're paranoid) just save the game, pick up the quests, then re-load if you don't get what you want. However, I dropped dozens of those quests to get the last radiant quest I needed in Markath and had no problems becoming Master of the Thieve's Guild.

Comment: I did it this way, too. It takes time and is frustrating, but it's really the only way.

Answer (score 2):

Ai, I feel your pain man. It took me a long time to get a job in Solitude as well. But fret-not friend, there are some. Make sure to visit both Vex and Delvin. It takes a while, and they'll probably get pissed, but a contract will come up. Try bedlam and burglary/sweep jobs, as burglary jobs target each city equally, and as there is one home in Solitude that attracts an unusual amount of guild activity.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution; after the civil war if you picked the Stormcloak's side, after you killed General Tullius, you need to go Castle Dour and talk with Ulfric. After that he should return the Windhelm and that bug disappears after that.

Answer (score -3):

Just keep accepting and dropping until your suitable quest appears

Comment: This answer adds nothing that isn't covered in more detail by the other two.